# remove a host from the completion list for ssh in zsh

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I once had some hosts named 'myhost', 'myhost1', etc. And now all those except 'myhost3' become invalid. I removed those from `/etc/hosts` and `~/.ssh/known_hosts`, but zsh still completes them for me. Is there any other file I should edit to make zsh forget about those hosts?

I haven't changed anything related to hosts in my zsh configuration; they come out by default.

UPDATE:

Some time later (after a hibernation but no reboot), those hosts disappear. Maybe zsh cleared some kind of cache? (But not `~/.zcompdump` as I checked that. I also tried start new instances of zsh but that doesn't make difference.)

I'll try and test later.

UPDATE #2:

I tried again and successfully removed a newly-added host from the completion list. Maybe I did something wrong previously, sorry.

Answer (score 9):

From experimentation, it looks like zsh is indeed using `.ssh/known_hosts` for its autocompletion, but it only reads that at startup/first use.

Deleting the offending host (`ssh-keygen -R hostname` or simply editing `.ssh/known_hosts`), then restarting the shell seems to work.

Comment: That worked for me too

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how zsh completes them, but my homegrown bash completion scripts also look at `~/.ssh/config`. Maybe check if the hosts are in there?

Alternatively, `strace -eopen` the zsh process while autocompleting and see where it looks :)

Comment: I've checked `~/.ssh/config` too. See my update please.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to delete your zsh completion cache, `~/.zcompdump` (or `$_comp_dumpfile` if you've changed the location).

Comment: I've checked that file too (by searching one of the hosts). See my update please.